# Find the next word after a keyword each time it's encountered

Tags: python, string, find, keyword

```
string = "Is your name Jack ? Wasn't your name Matthew ?"
split_string = string.split()
find_names = split_string[split_string.index("name") +1]

print(find_names)

#Output: Jack
```

My goal is to find the next word after a keyword is encountered every time, not only the first time. The output should be *Jack Matthew* instead of just Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could zip the list of words with itself to make adjacent pairs. Then for each pair, test if the first of the pair is `"name"`.

```
string = "Is your name Jack ? Wasn't your name Matthew ?"
split_string = string.split()

[name for test, name in zip(split_string, split_string[1:]) if test == 'name']
# ['Jack', 'Matthew']
```

Answer (score 0):

`index` takes a second optional argument of the index to begin the search in. So you could loop over the list and call index from the position of the previously find name until you find them all:

```py
ind = -1
while True:
    try:
        ind = split_string.index('name', ind + 1)
    except ValueError:
        break

    print(split_string[ind + 1])
```